# Python. Как получить значения словаря, которое является значением словаря

Tags: python

```
departments = {

    'продажи':{

        'сотрудники': ['Гришин', 'Иванова'],

        'менеджер': 'Иванова',

        'заведующий': 'Гришин'

    },
    'разработка':{

        'сотрудники': ['Васильев', 'Ежов', 'Петрова'],

        'менеджер': 'Ежова',

        'заведующий': 'Петрова'

    }

}

print(departments['продажи'].values())
```

Нужно замутить так, что бы в `print`, например, были все сотрудники. То, что сверху, это всё, до чего

я мог додуматься, дальше - уже не знаю, как.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если я вас правильно понял, то вам подойдёт такой способ:

```
print(departments['продажи']['сотрудники'])
```

В данном примере у вас двумерный словарь. Его св-ва несильно отличаются от двумерных массивов, потому можете почитать вот эту [статью](https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/2d_arrays/)

Answer (score 0):

```
print(departments['продажи']['сотрудники'] + departments['разработка']['сотрудники'])
```

Вот так, если я правильно понял условие